# -sed command in terminal complex command

Tags: bash, unix, sed, terminal, grep

I have .csv file with thousands of lines. Some of these lines contain ABC, some contains XYZ, and some contain something else (of which I am not sure). Is there any way to find lines that do not contain ABC or XYZ and identify them through the unix?

Essentially, I would like to be able to -grep all the lines that do not have either of the two ABC or XYZ to see what those lines are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Also include what you have tried so far and what problem(s) you are having solving this yourself (it sounds like 5 minutes reading the grep man page would produce the answer).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing "complex" about this.

```
grep -E -v 'ABC|XYZ' file | less
```

If you want to exclude lines containing *only exactly* these values, add an `-x` option, or add anchors to the regular expression; `'^(ABC|XYZ)$'`

You might want to replace the `less` with some deeper analysis.  The standard `| sort | uniq -c | sort -rn'` will produce a frequency count for different values, for example.

```
printf 'A\nB\nABC\nA\nB\nXYZ\nA\n' |
grep -E -v 'ABC|XYZ' |
sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

produces

```
   3 A
   2 B
```

As an aside, even plain old traditional `grep` can do this, at least in some dialects; just supply multiple `-e` options;

```
grep -v -e ABC -e XYZ file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex word (`\b`) boundaries is helpful when needing to be specific about the strings:

```
\bABC\b|\bXYZ\b
```

For example if you had a file with:

```
ABCXYZ
XYZ ABC
ABZ
```

Using the following would result in lines 1 and 3 being output:

```
grep -E -v '\bABC\b|\bXYZ\b' file
```

Without using word boundaries you would also not output `ABCXYZ`, which is not `ABC` or `XYZ`.

Comment: or use grep's `-w` switch to match only words.. `grep -E -vw 'ABC|XYZ' file`

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `sed`

```
sed '/ABC\|XYZ/d' ip.csv
```

- `/ABC\|XYZ/` matches lines containing `ABC` or `XYZ`
- `d` command deletes those lines

If you need to search those terms in case-insensitive manner, use the `I` flag

```
sed '/ABC\|XYZ/Id' ip.csv
```